# Rao Cramèr Lower Bound problem

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference, order-statistics, sufficient-statistics, cramer-rao

Let $X_1, · · · , X_n$ be a random sample from the uniform distribution on $[0, θ]$. I want to get the variance of the maximum likelihood estimator of $θ$ and check whether the variance decrease at the rate of $1/n$. Besides, whether the Cramèr-Rao information bound hold in this case.

For the first part, I got $$L(\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta^n} \mathbb I(X_{(n)} \leq \theta)$$

So, $$\hat \theta_{MLE} = \max(X_1,...,X_n)$$

For next step, I don't know how to calculate the variance of this MLE and don't know how to check the 2 questions. Any help or hint is welcome

Comment: The trick is to write down the density function of the maximum and either notice that its mean and variance are easy to compute or notice that it's a scaled Beta distribution.

Comment: One thing often ignored when computing the CRB is the regularity conditions. The Fisher information must be well-defined and the expectation and differentiation should be interchangeable. The 2nd condition when the support is bounded requires the support to be independent of the parameter being estimated.